# Adding attributes to radio buttons of radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I need to add some javascript function to the multiple radio buttons rendered using radio button list. Instead they are added to span created dynamically.  See the codes.

**RAW html/aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisplayAlert() {
            alert('hahahahahahahahhahah');

        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblAmit" AutoPostBack="false" 
     DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id">  </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div>
    <table id="rblAmit">
    <tr>
        <td><span onchange="javascript:DisplayAlert();"><input id="rblAmit_0" type="radio" name="rblAmit" value="A1" /><label for="rblAmit_0">Amit</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span onchange="javascript:DisplayAlert();"><input id="rblAmit_1" type="radio" name="rblAmit" value="A2" /><label for="rblAmit_1">Ranjan</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span onchange="javascript:DisplayAlert();"><input id="rblAmit_2" type="radio" name="rblAmit" value="A3" checked="checked" /><label for="rblAmit_2">Senior</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span onchange="javascript:DisplayAlert();"><input id="rblAmit_3" type="radio" name="rblAmit" value="A4" /><label for="rblAmit_3">Software</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span onchange="javascript:DisplayAlert();"><input id="rblAmit_4" type="radio" name="rblAmit" value="A5" /><label for="rblAmit_4">Engineer</label></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </div>
```

**CS-Codebehind**

```
private void FireEventOnLoad()
{

    foreach (ListItem item in rblAmit.Items)
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:DisplayAlert();");
    }

    if (rblAmit.Items.FindByText("Senior") != null)
    {
        rblAmit.Items.FindByText("Senior").Selected = true;
    }
}
```

**OR**

Any way so that I can enumerate RadioButtons from the RadioButtonList. Current I am getting a Key Value pair list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnChange events are associated with elements whose value attribute can change. You can use the onclick event instead and this will delegate to the input element under the span.

```
private void FireEventOnLoad()
{

    foreach (ListItem item in rblAmit.Items)
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:DisplayAlert();");
    }

    if (rblAmit.Items.FindByText("Senior") != null)
    {
        rblAmit.Items.FindByText("Senior").Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery for this.
Give Id to container DIV.

Write Javascript function and call that function on radiobutton list refresh.

Part of javascript function -

```
$('#container :radio').each(function(){
// attach onclick event.
 });
```